# IP as a method of access control? (IP Spoofing possibilities)

Tags: apache-2.2, ip

I'm currently investigating the use of IP addresses as a form of access control: for example, only allowing access to an Apache VirtualHost if the request originates from a specific IP address or range (eg: 192.168.100.0/24).

My concern is whether it is possible for somebody to spoof their IP address to make it appear as if their request originates from this address?

Comment: Does this help? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/what-security-risks-does-ip-spoofing-bring

Comment: If you are limiting it to one IP address on the same subnet, others on that subnet may be able to steal the allowed IP address.  That doesnt work beyond the same subnet, but may be something to be aware of.

Comment: @Grant Users would be connecting through a local IP subnet (eg: 192..) whereas I'd be restricting users from external subnets (can't firewall (easily, at least), because the server hosts external sites as well. Obviously the best solution would be to host on two servers, but cost is currently a concern.

Comment: @bnmcg as long as you are only restricting external IP addresses, what I mentioned won't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm currently investigating the use of IP addresses as a form of
>   access control: for example, only allowing access to an Apache
>   VirtualHost if the request originates from a specific IP address or
>   range

Yes, this is a reasonable security measure. It should not be your only security measure, though.

To expand on this:

Since you mention apache, I presume the protocol you're talking about is HTTP. HTTP utilizes TCP and therefore is immune to IP spoofing. Sure, someone could spoof the IP on the initial TCP SYN packet, but they will never be able to establish a TCP socket and thus, will never be able to issue HTTP requests to your server.

Comment: It depends a little bit on what you are defending against. If you are defending against DoS attacks in which somebody try to overload your server by invoking many instances of an expensive script, then it is reasonable to assume TCP is immune to IP spoofing, because it doesn't matter if the attacker succeeds in spoofing the IP once in a million times. But for access control you don't want to grant an attacker access once in a million times. And that is one part of the reason why IP address must not be the only part of the authentication.

Comment: @kasperd Authentication is also used on-site to authenticate users, this is just a first-line measure to try and stop unwanted users even accessing the authentication pages.